# Notation for residual sum of squares $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - f(x_i))^2$

Tags: statistics, summation, notation, regression

I’m reading the The Data Science Design Manual by Skiena and I need help with the notation on page 270.

> Linear regression seeks the line $y = f(x)$ which minimizes the sum of the squared errors over all the training points, i.e., the coefficient vector $w$ that minimizes
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{i=1}^{n}  &(y_i - f(x_i))^2 
> \tag{1}
> \\
> \textrm{where} 
> \quad 
> f(x) &= w_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{m-1}w_ix_i
> \tag{2}
> \end{align}
> Suppose we are trying to fit a set of $n$ points, each of which is $m$ dimensional. The first $m-1$ dimensions of each point is the feature vector $(x_1, \dots, x_{m-1})$, with the last value $y = x_m$ serving as the target or dependent variable.

My question: What is the difference between $f(x)$ and $f(x_i)$? It says “where” so shouldn’t (2) be $f(x_i)$?

I have seen a similar notation as in (1) before and I understand it if it is written as:
\begin{align}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n} & (y_i - \hat y_i)^2 
 \tag{3}
 \\
 \textrm{where} 
 \quad 
 \hat y_i &= a + b x_i
 \tag{4}
\end{align}
But I don’t follow the notation $f(x_i)$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a function. $f(x_i)$ is a constant. This is the value of $f(x)$ when $x=x_i$.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in the $x_i$ notation here, since in $f(x_i)$ it is one of the $n$ observations of $x$, while in $(x_1, \dots, x_{m-1})$ it is one of the $m-1$ (or $m$) elements of the multi-dimensional  $x$.  You can work out from the context each time, but there are better ways of presenting this.